# How to create a loop that prints out a given list (including numbers)

Tags: python, for-loop

The list contains different sandwich ingredients, such as the following:
ingredients=['snail', 'leeches',] and I have to create a loop that prints out the list(including the numbers:
1  snails
2 leeches

Comment: You should precise in which programming language.

Comment: It is  a python language

Comment: You should add a Python tag to your question.

Comment: Am new here, Please how do I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question, and answer:
[Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Basically, you just use a for loop, but instead of looping over your collection, you loop over your collection processed by the enumerate function.

Here is an example using more advanced constructs like list comprehension:

```py
ingredients = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]
for line in [f"{i} {e}" for i, e in enumerate(ingredients)]:
    print(line)
```

It will print

```
0 Foo
1 Bar
2 Baz
```

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that you're asking about Python, so you need to use `enumerate` with a for loop as follows:

```py
ingredients = ['snail', 'leeches']

for i, ingredient in enumerate(ingredients, 1):
    print(i, ingredient)
```

Note that the second argument of the `enumerate` function indicates the starting number, in this case, we need `1`.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked just as you explained